# jQuery unobtrusive validation - can't add in simple custom client validation rule

Tags: unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm trying to add a single, simple client-only validation rule while using jQuery unobtrusive. My validation function is never called, the alert never fires. What am I doing wrong? I've stripped this down from a much more complex MVC application.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.3/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("mysplit", function () {
        alert("in validator");
        return false;
    }, "Barf");
    result = jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("mysplit");
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" data-val="True", data-val-mysplit="error msg" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure if this matters for a simple .htm file but in my web.config, everything looks correct:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still unable to decorate an HTML element to make it work with unobtrusive validation. It appears that if you don't have an adaptor for your custom rule, then manually adding the unobtrusive HTML attributes will not work. However I did discover that you can decorate elements to be validated directly by jQuery.validate (more or less skipping the unobtrusive validation). I don't know if manually adding jQuery.validation data attributes this way will conflict with the validation done by unobtrusive if you have, for example, a [Required] attribute on the element that gets converted to the "data-val" attributes by unobtrusive.

In short you can add a client validation method with the usual jQuery.validator.addMethod() then trigger it with the proper data-rule attributes (**not** data-val, which unobtrusive uses). For example to validate that an input field has the value "hello", I can add a rule:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("hello", function (value, element, params) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^hello$/.test(value);
});
```

Note: don't add the error message param to addMethod, it will conflict with @Html.ValidationMessageFor() if you are using that.

Then manually decorate your HTML element like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.sendOn, new
{
    htmlAttributes = new
    {
        data_rule_hello="true"
    }
})
```

Any jQuery.validate will fire.

Note that trying to use data-rule-pattern="hello" just refused to work for me so I went the addMethod() route.

In my case rather that switch totally away from unobtrusive just because I can't validate this one input is a much worse option than this bit of a hack to do my custom validation of an input element or two here or there.

[This article](http://johnnycode.com/2014/03/27/using-jquery-validate-plugin-html5-data-attribute-rules/) was key to exposing the data-rule magic.

I have yet to find out if this technique causes any serious problems in production but it seems to work for me.

I would also recommend that people consider writing a custom adaptor for their own model attributes if they need custom validation instead of a one-off hack like this.